# Slow speeds when using D-Link DWA-140

Tags: wireless, usb

I've been trying to get my D-Link DWA-140(H/W working properly for quite some time. I've tried several guides including: [D'Link Wireless DWA-140 speeds are crippled on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131768/dlink-wireless-dwa-140-speeds-are-crippled-on-12-04) but I still have slow and unstable connection. What do I do?

I notice that compiling that file gave me rt5370sta but shouldn't it be RT3072?

Here is some more information:
`mattias@ubuntudator:~$ lsusb`

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 07d1:3c0a D-Link System DWA-140 RangeBooster N Adapter(rev.B2) [Ralink RT3072]`

`lsmod | grep ^rt`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rt5370sta             805299  0
rt2800usb              22684  0 
rt2800lib              58925  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb              20762  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              55301  3 rt2800usb,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb

crc_ccitt              12667  1 rt2800lib
```

`sudo modprobe -rf rt5370sta`
No reaction

`sudo modprobe -rf rt2800usb`
Disconnected

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have to blacklist all your rt mods except the rt5370sta one.

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add those lines:

```
blacklist rt2800usb
blacklist rt2800lib
blacklist rt2x00usb
blacklist rt2x00lib
```

Then reboot.

Check this guide for a new installation: https://luismi.sanchezarteaga.es/instalacion-de-d-link-wifi-usb-dwa-140b3-en-ubuntu-12-04-lts/
It's in spanish, but commands are well explained. I've followed it and my DWA-140/B3 is working great.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that my DWA-140 had massive interference with my wireless headset (Logitech H600, H800 is the same hardware). As soon as I turned the headset off the connection was perfect. When the headset was on the speed would drop dramatically and the ping times were about 10x longer. Probably other 2.4GHz devices can cause the same issue so be advised to check radio frequencies of all your wireless devices. In the end I fixed it by going wired with my internet connection.